# Remove duplicate rows by value

Tags: sql

I need to perform a group by, but only on rows that meet a condition, otherwise return all rows that do not meet the condition. For example, in the following table, I want to group only rows that have '1' in the "active" field, and return all rows that do not.

TABLE (id, label, active):

```
1, A, 1
2, A, 1
3, B, 0
4, B, 0
```

Would return:

```
1, A, 1
3, B, 0
4, B, 0
```

Comment: That's a pretty ambiguous question. Waiting for an update of significant size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simplest way I can think of.  It is a case statement in the group by.  If the condition is met then group by the label, otherwise group by the primary key.

```
SELECT id, label, active
FROM table
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN active = 1 THEN active
    ELSE id END
```

If you want to group by active and label:

```
SELECT id, label, active
FROM table
GROUP BY
  CASE
    WHEN active = 1 THEN active
    ELSE id END,
  label
```

EDIT: I misunderstood which field you want to group on.  Corrected now.

Comment: I love it when the answer is so simple I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CASE statement

```
select min(id) as id, label, active
from (
     select id, label, active,
           case
             when active = 1 then 'active'
             else convert(varchar,newid()) as discriminator
           end
     from table) t
group by label, active, discriminator
```

this will give a common value to all rows that meet the condition (active = 1) and a unique value to all other rows so that they remain ungrouped.

I don't have access to SQL server at the moment so this is completely untested.

Comment: So...
SELECT id, label, active, case when active = 1 then null else convert(varchar,newid()) end as groupit group by groupit

Unfortunately, I will be using aggregate functions on a lot of other fields that are also returned, but I think I can get the raw data to group first as a sub select, and then join the miscellaneous data.

Comment: I prefer my method since there is no subquery and repurposing the id field as the unique option in the case statement reduces a couple of function calls.

However, if going with this one I think you have to remove the id column from the GROUP BY clause.  Otherwise it will return all rows with no grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the layout of the query could be something like this:

```
select
  min(id),
  label,
  max(active)
from
  Foo
where
  active = 1
group by
  label

union

select
  id,
  label,
  active
from
  Foo
where
  active = 0
```